# Visual Studio 2012 colour theme format

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-2012

I've found the colour theme settings for Visual Studio 2012 at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Themes

I can duplicate a dark output window in the light scheme by copying the relevant key so this is definitely where the color comes from (you have to restart the IDE in-between changes).

I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with the format of the binary data in these keys?

Or the Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\ShellColors.pkgdef file that they seem to be created from?

I've tried some experimentation with changing what I guess should be the colour values with without much success.

Comment: It's good to know I'm not the only one digging around trying to change the colors in the new horrible-hard-on-the-eyes interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this theme editor I wrote that helps you modify the built-in colors of the Dark/Light themes. Most of Visual Studio's Windowing colors are in the **Environment** category.

More info here:

[Modify Visual Studio 2012 Dark (and Light) Themes](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/08/27/modify-visual-studio-2012-dark-and-light-themes.aspx)

[Visual Theme Editor 2012 Source Code](http://github.com/bchavez/VisualThemeEditor2012)

Comment: Thanks for that but I couldn't get anything working using your editor. Maybe that's my 64-bit development machine - the new colors didn't seem to be saving to the registry. 

What did work as a temporary solution was I copied the key name from the high contrast theme (a5c004b4-2d4b-494e-bf01-45fc492522c7 on my machine) and used that as the current theme at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\Current Theme. Not what I actually wanted but a damn sight better than the Dark or Light options.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works. I'm on 64-bit too. Perhaps you changed a color value that gets painted over. For example, change **Environment > CommandBarMenuBorder** and click on FILE or EDIT, and you'll see menu border color changed. Maybe I should write a global contrast adjustment to all colors that adjusts all colors globally in 10% steps or something. Might help for those who just want to lighten up the dark theme (or darken the light theme)  without poking around with individual colors.

Comment: Also, you might want to try this **Midnight** theme by Eugen Podsypalnikov: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/444787/Midnight-A-VS2012-Middle-Theme

Comment: Also, the theme editor does not work with 2012 Express editions without a registry path adjustment located in the comments section on my blog.

Comment: Here is my vs2010 like theme: http://www.cihanyakar.com/2010theme.zip
preview: http://i.imgur.com/NHDq3.png